# Relationships and with in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Structure:

```
**galleries**

id
location
open_to_public

**pictures**
id
title
published

**gallery_picture**
gallery_id
picture_id
```

Model:

```
class Galleries extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'galleries';

public function pictures(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('pictures', 'gallery_picture', 'gallery_id', 'picture_id');

}
```

I have the same model as above for pictures.

My question is, I pass in a picture id, then I need to get all of the pictures that belong to the passed in pictures id's gallery.

So far I have:

```
Pictures::with('galleries')->whereId($id)->get();
```

But this only returns a single picture.

Comment: does your `Picture` model have a `$this->hasMany('Galleries')` function ?

Comment: @w0rldart Yes it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to a question asked yesterday, merging all the hasMany objects of a collection is something that Laravel does not yet do out of the box. You need to write your own loop:

```
// we'll eventually have all pictures here
$pictures = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

// get all galleries of the given picture
$galleries = Picture::find($id)->galleries;

// iterate through the galleries and add their pictures to our large set
foreach ($galleries as $gallery) {
    $pictures->merge($gallery->pictures);
}
```

If it wasn't a `belongsToMany` relationship but simply `Gallery hasMany Picture`, `Picture belongsTo Gallery` then one line of code would have worked:

```
$pictures = Picture::find($id)->gallery->pictures;
```

But in this case a given picture has to have one gallery to which it belongs.